# Can't append a set of values from a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a card game.
The class is called `Card`:
It can give a random value with the `deal()` method to display a random card from the numbers 1-13
The other file will import the file name that contains the Class Card. It will call the class 5 times and be able to store it by appending it on a list and displaying it in another def called `display_hand`

Here is the class file:

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0

    def deal(self):
        self.__value = random.randint(1, 13)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def find_face_value(self):
        faces = ['Joker','Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six',
             'Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King']
        return faces[self.__value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.find_face_value()
```

The program is too big so this is the def for calling the function 5 times:

```
def deal_hand():  
    # Create an empty list to append the cards.
    hand = []
    deal_hand = classcard3.Card()

    for i in range(1, 6):
        deal_hand = classcard3.Card()
        deal_hand.deal()
        # Create a new object in memory and assign it to the
        # hand variable 
        w = classcard3.Card(deal_hand)
        # add it to the list
        hand.append(w)

    return hand
```

Here is the display function:

```
def display_hand(hand):
    print ("The 5-card hand is: ")
    for item in hand:
        print(hand)
```

This is not showing anything except for the print inside the loop. How can I pass it to the display hand to show the cards?
This is the only thing that shows whenever I use the print function inside the loop. I'm trying to use it outside and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. My apologies if I'm not explaining this too well. I'm a beginner at python and new to this website. Thanks

```
deal Four
deal Three
deal Five
deal Six
deal Queen
```

The only error that I'm getting from this is:

```
line 274, in deal_hand
    w = classcard3.Card(deal_hand)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This doesn't make sense, because I'm doing it just as the book says and is not willing to display the values

Comment: What do you expect `classcard3.Card(deal_hand)` to do? `Card.__init__` doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: Well as the book says. We create a new object in memory and assign it to the w variable?

Comment: What I want to do is append it to the hand list and display it by doing the display_hand

Comment: what is `classcard3`?

Comment: As an aside, It may be less confusing if you don't mask names. You have a function called `deal_hand` that has a local variable `deal_hand` which makes it more difficult to talk about your code.

Comment: classcard3.py is the file name. I'm sorry if this is confusing but I am myself trying to understand this. I been sitting on this for a while because I just can't figure it out why is not displaying

Comment: This is what is asking: 


Instead of putting the integer value for each card in a list, you will create an object of type Card, invoke the deal() method, then append it to your list.

There is a good example to refer to on page 516.

Your deal hand function will pass the list of objects to the display hand function and the hand stats function, so you will need to modify the code in each of those functions so they reference the data attributes in the object rather than just an integer value in a list like it currently does.

Comment: You use the `Card` class without problem with `deal_hand = classcard3.Card()`. Then you use the same class incorrectly here `w = classcard3.Card(deal_hand)` - what is that supposed to do? Shouldn't you have just done `hand.append(deal_hand)` to put the card into the hand?

Comment: Tdelaney, thats how I had it to begin with but is just not displaying anything. So I tried it doing it how the book said and is still not working. I cant print it inside the loop and it will show but is not doing it whenever I send it to the display_hand function

Comment: @tdelaney is correct. The reason it wasn't displaying is that in your display function, it should be `print(item)` not `print(hand)`

Comment: I switch it to `item` and it still not displaying. I'm done XD